# Multithread in NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, multithreading, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

When we use NSURLConnection, we just need implement the delegate API

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

to receive data. If need long time for network to return data,those staff should not be stay at main thread. So we should take the asynchronous mode.

There must be multithreading implementation behind NSURLConnection, is that correct ? If no,how do you think ?

Comment: Why you don't want it to stay at the main thread? I mean what the problem that could caused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSURLConnection should be started in main thread. Please refer the following link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1712/_index.html